# Error: dynamic import() syntax failing randomly

Tags: webpack, import

I was once able to build my node module in specific webpack application that is now failing with the following error:

```
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not 
possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

I was able to successfully build these applications and suddenly it stopped working(no changes in applications or node module). What reason could this error be generated?

In addition, the import statement has `/* webpackIgnore: true */`, which use to resolve the issue, but now it is failing.